# Manipulate SVG viewbox with JavaScript (no libraries)

Tags: javascript, svg, viewbox

I'm trying to alter an SVG elements viewbox in JavaScript. Basically, I'm drawing a binary search tree, and when it gets too wide, I want to alter the viewbox to zoom out so that the tree fits in the window. I'm currently using:

```
if(SVGWidth>=1000){
  var a = document.getElementById('svgArea');
  a.setAttribute("viewbox","0 0 " + SVGWidth + " 300");
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<svg id="svgArea" xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink"; width="1000" height="300" viewBox="0 0 1000 300">
```

I've also tried using setAttributeNS('null',...) but that didn't seem to work either. One strange thing I've noticed is that when I alert(a) it gives [object SVGSVGElement] which seems strange. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: may I know why you don't want to use libraries?

Comment: I should have added, SVGWidth is probably a bad variable name, should just be treeWidth. Also, the html for the SVG is:
    <svg id="svgArea" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000" height="300" viewBox="0 0 1000 300">

Comment: I'm not using libraries because I'm focusing on learning JavaScript. My next project I'll add in libraries, but I thought it would be best to start with native JavaScript.

Comment: @aclear16 : Probably using a library to achieve this would be frustrating, since it should work and since it would only limit the OP's general understanding of DOM manipulation (and thus they would be at the mercy of the library).  While we shouldn't be expected to understand things down to the assembly level, it's always helpful to understand how something you are already working within actually works rather than rely on libraries.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It would be good to see the context of the svg, but the following worked for me with a pure SVG document:

```
shape = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
shape.setAttribute("viewBox", "-250 -250 500 750");
```

Maybe it's because `viewBox` is case-sensitive?

Comment: Look at it this way, if it hadn't been that easy, it would have been harder.  And I never tried messing with the actual svg element attributes until now, so we both figured something out.

Comment: <cries> I made the same mistake.

Comment: For dynamically created SVGs, the SVG element would need to be created using `createElementNS` or else setting the attribute `viewBox` would not work. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734628/how-can-i-set-an-attribute-with-case-sensitive-name-in-a-javascript-generated-el/28734954#28734954

Comment: More precisely, the DOM SVG object has only `viewBox` attribute. is has no `viewbox` attribute, even though you write `viewbox` in the HTML

Comment: I believe that this should be `setAttributeNs(null, "viewBox", ...)` and that `setAttribute` *happens* to work, but may not work in the future.  Please correct me if I am mistaken, since I am not 100% sure on this.

Comment: @CharlesL. - I think you are correct. I said as much myself on another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546135/appending-path-child-within-svg-using-javascript/10546700#10546700

Comment: I can confirm that `viewBox` *is* case sensitive.

Answer (score 13):

You have an error in your code: "viewbox" is different than "viewBox"...B is in uppercase. Change the code to:

```
a.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 " + SVGWidth + " 300");
```

Comment: Well, I think the way the answer now is does answer the question. The 'b' was the reason it didn't work. However, user3434597 should have read @Anthony's older answer first. Maybe he'll remove this one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar use case, where resizing SVG was crucial for responsive design.

```
const windowWidth = window.innerWidth ||
  document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
  document.body.clientWidth;

const windowHeight = window.innerHeight ||
  document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
  document.body.clientHeight;

// used getElementById for specific SVG
const shape = document.getElementById("background-svg");

function onWindowResize(){
console.log(windowWidth, windowHeight);

if (windowWidth < 600 || windowHeight < 900) {
  shape.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 400 800");
}

// Added an Event Listener
window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
```

This method worked well enough for me, I hope there's room for improvement, would be glad to find alternative solutions. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you want to set the view box dimension dynamically then use ES6 template literals instead of string concatenation.

```
shape = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
const view = `${xValue} ${yValue} ${width} ${height}`; // template literals
shape.setAttribute("viewBox", view);
```